# Spring batch writer: add a terminator record after a group of records

Tags: spring-batch

I have a step where I need to read some rows from a db table and, for each row, write a record (for example in a sequential file, but this should not be important).

Each row belongs to a group and after processing all the rows of one group I need to add a "termination record" with some information like the record count for that group (I can sort when reading to ensure all the rows of the same group are adjacent).

I was trying to do this implementing the ItemStreamWriter interface, keeping the last group written in a property and writing the termination record before an item of a different group is written:

```
private Group group = null;

public void write(List<? extends Record> data) {
    for (Record item : data) {
        if(group==null) {
            group = item.getGroup();
        } else if(!group.equals(item.getGroup())) {
            addTeminationRecord(group);
            group = item.getGroup();
        }

        addRegularRecord();
    }
}
```

The problem is that I don't know when to write the last termination record. I was thinking at the "close" method but there I don't know if the stream is closed because the stem completed or after a failure.

A different solution I considered is to use a reader to load entire groups (ItemReader) with the record's list as a property of the group. The problem is that the number of record per group is really high and the record include much data and this would cause different problems (memory, too much work lost if the transaction need to be rollbacked, ecc.)

Is there a different way to obtain what I need?

**UPDATE:** I need to add the termination record only when the last record of the group is processed.
In my understanding the footerCallback of FlatFileItemWriter always write the footer, even in case the step execution was interrupted.
Am I right?

Answer (score 0):

You're right, footerCallback of FlatFileItemWriter will always be called even if there's an error in writing the records. You can pass the "group" variable to the footer callback (e.g., through ItemStream) and the callback can refer to the latest "group" and write if it's not null. So you don't have to care/define the last group before you start writing.

Alternative: Following your current setup, I'm thinking if it's possible for you to get the number of records you are expecting to read. Using that count, inform your writer so it knows when to write the last termination record.